# 561 Euler pseudoprime bases

Tags: number-theory, pseudoprimes

I am asked to find all bases for which 561 is an Euler pseudoprime. Unfortunately, the lecturer did not tell us how to do this in a systematic way.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $a$ such that $a^{280} \equiv \pm 1 (\text{mod } 561)$.  Since 
$561 = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17$, the congruence must be true mod $3$, mod $11$ and mod $17$.
For example, $a^{280} \equiv 1 (\text{mod } 11)$ for all $a$ coprime to $11$, because $280$ is divisible by $10$.  Now, what about mod $3$ and mod $17$?